# Problem with third key characters

Tags: keyboard, locale

I've just installed Rasbian, everything works well except the third key characters

> @, #, ], [

I use english locale and italian keymap.

How could I solve this problem?

PS: All the other character are used correctly, in the right position.

Comment: Just to clarify, but by third key do you mean the '3' key? If not, then what key?

Comment: The character of italian keyboard: @, #, [ and ] Example: http://km.support.apple.com/library/APPLE/APPLECARE_ALLGEOS/HT2841/Italian.gif but I can write ò, à, ç, ecc..

Comment: OK, I understand now. I'm used to these on Swedish keyboards as being called the AltGr characters. Is this problem occurring in the console or in X11?

Comment: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/41032/i-changed-my-raspberry-pi-default-keyboard-settings-how-can-i-reset-this-change  please follow this.