# I changed my Raspberry Pi default keyboard settings. How can I reset this change?

Tags: raspbian, python, keyboard, reset

I changed my Raspberry Pi keyboard (using command the `sudo nano /etc/default/keyboardp`). I set:

```
XKBLAYOUT = 'in'
```

Now, after reboot I just can't login! Can I somehow reset this CHANGE?

Comment: You could try to login through `ssh` as suggested in [this related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19197979/unable-to-login-to-raspberry-pi-linux-after-locale-change).

Comment: You could try googling an Indonesian keyboard layout to use the correct keys.

Comment: Indonesian? Isn't 'in' for 'India'?

Comment: One doubt: "I just can't login!" -> means that your keyboard not working at all, or only that it gives other characters than your own keyboard layout?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you know the IP address you can `ssh` from another machine. Then use the `raspi-config` utility:

Open a terminal

1. Run `raspi-config`
2. Choose `Localisation Options`
3. Choose `Change Keyboard Layout`
4. Choose your keyboard or one of the generics
5. Choose your langauge. For instance, for American English choose
   `English (US)`
6. `sudo reboot`

Alternatively to `ssh`, if you have proper partitions on your SD card you can:

1. Insert it into your laptop
2. Change keyboard setting with `vim /Volumes/<card name>/etc/default/keyboard` to `XKBLAYOUT="in"` to `XKBLAYOUT="us"` or whatever suits your need

Answer (score 5):

Can you insert the SD card into another machine and mount the filesystem?

If so, edit `/etc/default/keyboard` and change `XKBLAYOUT="in"` back to your desired setting.

If needed, there's a [list of valid codes on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1#Current_codes).

Answer (score 2):

You have switched to an Indic keyboard, though it's hard to know which one. They look quite different depending on which one was selected. There are some examples here: http://wiki.laptop.org/go/Keyboard_layouts#Indic

You basically have two choices: use another machine to `ssh` into you pi and fix it, or reflash your pi and start over.